# Python Libraries Aren't Carrying Over to Atom

Tags: python

I'm making a Discord bot with Python, and I had installed the discord.py library using `pip install`. When I try to run my python file, Python tells me that there isn't a module named Discord (`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord'`).

I was wondering why this is happening and if there are any fixes?

Comment: This is often because you have more than one Python environment and/or version, and you've installed into one of them but are running from a different one.  This is especially easy to do if you're running from inside an IDE or editor, but you're installing modules at the command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

i think in atom there is a packages tab, you may be able to get it from there, if not i recommend just using sublime text 3 since it doesn't use a virtual env and uses the system python interpreter so any modules you install using pip will work.